# Loading many images in PyGame with limited RAM

Tags: python, pygame

I'm using PyGame on a Raspberry Pi, so I only have 512mb of RAM to work with. I have to load and display a lot of images in succession, though. I can't naively load all of these images into RAM as PyGame surfaces - I don't have enough RAM. The images themselves are fairly small, so I assume that PyGame surfaces are fairly big, and this is why I run out of RAM. I've tried loading from the disk every time I want to display an image, but that's obviously slow (noticeably so).

Is there a reasonable way to display lots of images in succession in PyGame with limited RAM - either by keeping the size in memory of the PyGame surface as low as possible, or some other way?

Comment: Try converting your images to an uncompressed format like BMP or TGA and not JPG or PNG. Uncompressed images will load faster. Also add up the size of the uncompressed images, this should be the total size these images up in memory. If total size of the images is less than 128 MB or so then there's likely something you can do fix your code so it doesn't use so much memory. If it's in the range of 128 MB to 512 MB then its progressively less likely there's anything you can do.

Comment: The total is on the order of 2MB - it's really tiny. That's why I think that PyGame surfaces must be huge.

Comment: I don't think so, probably something else in your code. You should update your question with an example that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your files to bmp, it should help. If you have really that little ram, then you should lower the resolution of your files using an image editor such as Preview or Paintbrush. Also, space might be saved through more efficient programming, such as putting objects in a list and just calling a list update.

Comment: The objects are already in a list - that's why I run out of RAM. I'm unsure how lowering the resolution will help, given that the files are already pretty small. Why is bmp helpful?